# want to change label text on selecting drop down list by SQL but it is not happening

Tags: c#-4.0

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Plan" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Plan_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

MY back-end code is below

```
protected void Plan_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String strQuery = "SELECT pduration FROM Plans WHERE Pdetails" + " = @Pdetails";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pdetails", Plan.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Label3.Text = sdr["pduration"].ToString();
    con.Close();
}
```

please help me when i am selecting the drop down my label value is not changing .

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `SqlDataReader` you have to start reading it with [`SqlDataReader.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using(var sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(str.Read())
    {
        Label3.Text = sdr.GetString(0);
    }
}
```

You can also use a loop: `while(str.Read()){...}`. But i assume that you expect only one.

In that case you don't need a `SqlDataReader`. You can use a `SqlCommand` and use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) if only a single value is returned:

```
Label3.Text = (string) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: i want to change the value on selecting the drop down  but in this case it can change the value after refreshing the page

Comment: i want to change the value on selecting the drop down but in this case it can change the value after refreshing the page

Comment: @sandeep: you have to set the dropdownlists AutoPostBack property to true.

Comment: @sandeep: but you don't want to accept the answer anyway?